# how to sort item of alphanumeric type of string using sort method in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This is my data

```
val data = ArrayList<Product>()
        data.add(Product(it=1,type = "Ait 45"))
        data.add(Product(it=2,type = "Ait 35"))
        data.add(Product(it=3,type = "Ait 65"))
        data.add(Product(it=4,type = "Ait 325"))
        data.add(Product(it=5,type = "Ait 42"))
```

I am trying sort data based on type in descending order which is string type

expected output after sort

data should  =  `{(it=2,type = "Ait 35"),(it=5,type = "Ait 42"),(it=1,type = "Ait 45"),(it=3,type = "Ait 65"),(it=4,type = "Ait 325")}`

Please help me how to sort item using sort method in kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.sortedBy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) function from the standard library which returns a new list with the sorted elements or [`MutableList<T>.sortBy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) which sorts the elements in-place (moves the current list's items around to sort them).

Both of these functions `sortedBy` and `sortBy` have their `sortedByDescending` and `sortByDescending` counterparts.

Note that the following code will sort the strings by text, if you want to sort by the integer value contained into the "type" string you'd need to convert that value into an integer by manipulating the string contents.

```kotlin
data class Product(val it: Int,val type: String)

fun main() {
    val data = ArrayList<Product>()
    data.add(Product(it=1,type = "Ait 45"))
    data.add(Product(it=2,type = "Ait 35"))
    data.add(Product(it=3,type = "Ait 65"))
    data.add(Product(it=4,type = "Ait 325"))
    data.add(Product(it=5,type = "Ait 42"))
    println(data.sortedBy { it.type})
    println(data.sortedByDescending { it.type})
}
```

See the code in action inside the [Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/6y9btIsjB)

Comment: Method threw 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' exception.   this exception is coming @Some random IT boy

Comment: Something else you're doing is likely to cause that exception. Check the playground code: https://pl.kotl.in/6y9btIsjB

Comment: The OP seems to want it sorted in place, so maybe ``sortBy`` instead. There's also ``sortByDescending`` (and one for all the other variations), but their example output is sorted *ascending* - might be worth mentioning anyway since they did specify descending

Comment: That's a good point, I'll update my answer accordingly